# Steering Alexa towards a specific slot value response

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I've defined a custom slot types in the Amazon Developer console, the slot contains a list of names, as below.

```
homer simpson
ned flanders
principal skinner
comic book guy
```

I've then defined the sample utterances as below.

```
PlayAudio to play {Name}
```

So in the end, I want the user to be able to say something similar to the folliowing:

> Alexa, ask the simpsons to play homer simpson
>
> Alexa, ask the simpsons to play ned flanders
>
> Alexa, ask the simpsons to play principal skinner
>
> Alexa, ask the simpsons to play comic book guy

Of course, there is an extremely high chance that Alexa will hear the name incorrectly, so I need to be able to match the name that is heard as closely as possible one of the slot values.

How would I go about doing this, would I have to code it in the function or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that there is a high chance 'that Alexa will hear the name incorrectly'.  My solution is to do a bunch of trial and error with human testers to discover what the common mis-interpretations are, and then hard-code fixes for those.

So I get a tester to say the different names and make a record of what they said.  I then look at what Alexa gives me as the slot value, and where there are discrepencies I add a hard-coded substitution to my skill.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your answer, I was starting to head down that same method as I was struggling to see any other feasible way. Many thanks! 

Comment: Yup, no problem.  If you're not waiting for other answers then please mark as accepted.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

When using custom slots, there is a chance that Alexa will provide a value not in the list. This gets specially problematic as the list grows in size. Using the beta testing functionality as Tom suggested can help but you won't be able to catch all the issues and eventually this will not scale.

I found out that the only way to completely ensure you are getting a value from your list is to have the full list in the skill and check against it every time. In order to check, exact matching is not always the best option and I've tried two approaches:

- String Edit Distance functions: work well when a used may say incomplete utterances or add words to the utterances in your list. Check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance
- Acoustic/Phonetic: relatively easy to implement may work better for identifying foreign words or proper names. You can preprocess your list for quick comparisons. Check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex